# CRUD Create new Customer with using DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to create an application using the knowledge i;ve learnt from Domain Driven Design.

My issue is that in my application I need to be able to create a new customer capturing the customers address, phone number, email address etc, would I just use the standard CRUD style here as this isnt really a task based action?

Answer (score 4):

If all your application is ever going to do is to store customer data in a database, it's probably much better to use a simple CRUD style application.  If the customer entry is just part of a bigger application, then it's perfectly reasonable to have a form to enter customer data (such as name, address, ...) - the data has to be entered somehow.

Just be aware of the differences between task-based and CRUD style forms:  Say you'd want a customer to be flagged as verified, and for you have a state on the customer that can be "NEW" or "VERIFIED".  In a CRUD-style application one would simply use a select box with the two options "NEW" and "VERIFIED" that changes the customer's state field.  In a task-based UI you'd have a button/link in the customer form that reads "verify" and starts the "verification task", e.g., by sending a "verify customer" command to your domain layer.

Note that domain-driven-design is orthogonal to the concept task-based actions.  They play well together, particularly when one uses CQRS, but they can both be used independently of the other.

Comment: Would you say CRUD is ok to use to input the data initially then i can go task based thereafter e.g if i wanted to verify a user?

Comment: Sorry, I have problems to understand what you have in mind.  Wouldn't that be duplicate effort?